# Query for get Execution Time in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics, grafana-api

I used Grafana ,Prometheus and Metrics

I need to Prometheus Query for get Execution-Time(Latency) for each request process

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Prometheus server >= 2.16, you can enable [query logging](https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/query-log/). This will log all the queries made and their stats/timings.